# How to stop Windows 7 Built-in-Backup creating a System Image of too many drives?

Tags: windows-7, backup, symbolic-link, hardlink

I **do not want** to include (D:) drive in the image.

I believe I know the cause of this, it's because I have some *Directory Junctions* and/or *Symbolic Links*.

Any suggestions other than removing the *MKLINKS*?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a tweet from [@MSAU](https://twitter.com/MSAU/) [here](https://twitter.com/#!/MSAU/status/72268654074535936).

I believe I found out it was a service, that was installed to D: it was *iBackup* not sure if I chose it to be installed there or it chose an additional drive as C: was the target of the backup.

Simply uninstalling this removed D: from the list of drives to include in the image.

[image: Tweet snapshot]

Comment: Any clues on how to find those services?

Answer (score 4):

To find  list of services using "D" try this command

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%G IN ('sc query type^= service ^| find /I ^"SERVICE_NAME^"') DO sc qc %%G | find /I "BINARY_PATH_NAME"
```